# How to add a short description to each product on woocommerce shop page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hello thanks for reading, Just had a issue regarding woocommerce, I want to add a short 5-10 word description for each product on the shop page. Do i create a custom field, fill out the short description section??

I don't want it to appear on the product description page (when you click the product)

Sorry new to wordpress/woocommerce!

Would post an image for example but don't have enough rep :(

Thanks!

Comment: Please use the the_excerpt(); codex to display short description.

Answer (score 0):

**To add a short 5-10 word description for each product on the shop page**

create a function and then hook to that filter... something like this...

```
add_filter('woocommerce_short_description', 'limit_woocommerce_short_description', 10, 1);
function limit_woocommerce_short_description($post_excerpt){
    if (!is_product()) {
    $pieces = explode(" ", $post_excerpt);
    $post_excerpt = implode(" ", array_splice($pieces, 0, 10));
    }
    return $post_excerpt;
}
```

paste this in your **functions.php** file of your theme.

and use below code where you want to **display product description** -

```
<?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt ); ?>
```

use this code to **change word limit on the Shop Page not Product-detailed Page**.

Answer (score 0):

In functions.php you can add the code below for having the short description on each product when viewing them in shop page.Afterwards, you can change it through php code or javascript.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'output_product_excerpt', 35 );

function output_product_excerpt() {
global $post;
echo $post->post_excerpt;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 5);
```

Comment: Could you add some additional explanation, please!?